# [Android][Retrofit] result always return 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable

Tags: android, service, retrofit

I'm working on Android and handle mysql by retrofit

I encounter with issue when get respond :

"Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=503, message=Service Temporarily Unavailable, url=https://example.com/Server/getbanner.php}"

My code :

```
APIService.java
public class APIService {
    private static String base_url = "https://example.com/Server/";
    public static DataService GetService(){
        return APIRetrofitClient.GetClient(base_url).create(DataService.class);
    }
}

APIRetrofitClient.java
public class APIRetrofitClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    public static Retrofit GetClient(String base_url) {
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
                .protocols(Arrays.asList(Protocol.HTTP_1_1))
                .build();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(base_url)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
        return retrofit;
    }
}

DataService.java
public interface DataService {
    @GET("getbanner.php")
    Call<List<QuangCao>> GetDataBanner();
....
}


...
    public void GetDataBanner() {
        DataService dataService = APIService.GetService();
        Call<List<QuangCao>> callback = dataService.GetDataBanner();
        callback.enqueue(new Callback<List<QuangCao>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<QuangCao>> call, Response<List<QuangCao>> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    MainActivity.banners = (ArrayList<QuangCao>) response.body();
                    Log.d("Nhut", "get banners = " + response.body().toString());
                }else{
                    try {
                        Log.d("Nhut", "get banners fail 11= " + response.toString());
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        Log.d("Nhut","Exception :" +e.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<QuangCao>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("Nhut","get banners fail = " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

Note : https://example.com/Server/getbanner.php : return result on Browser is normal

Can you give me advise to solve it ?

Comment: Well 503 usually means server unavailable. Are you sure you are getting response on browser at the same time you get this error. Check your apis with Postman perhaps

Comment: I sure it.  Before that my app is active good on host free,  but when I move it to host paid , it isn't active on android, but when I check that link on Browser , it still active good.

Comment: I found fixed it. By it return from cloudflare host so we need register a domain name and upload files server to real host